# Are car upgrades purely cosmetic?

Tags: cruisn-blast

Each car in *Cruis'n Blast* (Switch) has upgrades that can be purchased such as neon, decals, body kit, and engine. Do these upgrades affect the car's stats, or are they purely cosmetic?

[image: Upgrading a car]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Car stats increase when your car levels up. Other upgrades are purely cosmetic and have no effect on stats.**

I tested this by comparing the stats of the 1959 Corvette when it was level 1 without upgrades, level 5 without upgrades, and level 5 with all upgrades.

Level 1 without upgrades
[image: Level 1 without upgrades]

Level 5 without upgrades
[image: Level 5 without upgrades]

Level 5 with all upgrades
[image: Level 5 with all upgrades]